# select required data from numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

Want to select the data between 1 and 4, and convert others as np.nan
But what's is the soluton?

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
selected = np.where(1<data<4, data, np.nan)
print (selected)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/fe/Desktop/t.py", line 3, in <module>
    selected = np.where(1<data<4, data, np.nan)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are very close, you just need a different way to select the relevant indices in `data`. Try:

```
>>> selected = np.where((data < 4) & (data > 1), data, np.nan)
>>> selected
array([ nan,   2.,   3.,  nan,  nan])
```

`(data < 4) & (data > 1)` finds the indices of the `data` that are BOTH `< 4` and `>1`.